# Filter Get-Mailbox by LegacyExchangeDN

Tags: exchangewebservices, powershell-3.0

I am getting the accounts able to creat meetings in rooms with this:

```
Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity ARoom | select -ExpandProperty BookInPolicy
```

This gets me the LegacyExchangeDN of the accounts. But when I try to get the Exchange-mailboxes with the following code, PowerShell starts listing all accounts available.

```
foreach ($i in $a) {Get-Mailbox -filter {LegacyExchangeDN -like $i}}
```

Being in a large organisation there is some 20k mailboxes, and it doesn't list the wanted result.
If I use one of the LegacyExchangeDN's in

```
"/o=ExchangeLabs/..." | Get-Mailbox -Filter {LegacyExchangeDN -like $_}
```

it gets the mailbox as intended.

So how do I get all the accounts from a rooms BookInPolicy via LegacyExchangeDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that filtering is not necessary. You can get the mailaccounts with simply:

```
Get-Mailbox $i.LegacyExchangeDN
```

So this code gets everything:

```
Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity ARoom | select -ExpandProperty BookInPolicy | % {Get-Mailbox $_}
```